# Targeting a specific NIC when listening for UDP (using UdpClient)

Tags: c#, .net, udp

I've got multiple 'sensors', each sending me packets via UDP on a separate point-to-point cable, and each to it's own network card.

I'm toying with having one thread/process per NIC, and would like to know if it's possible to target a specific NIC when using UdpClient to receive packets. And also if it's even worth the effort - is the automatic routing already efficient enough for me to just listen on a specific IP?